# Save values of dynamic generated HTML using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I m generating dynamic html with its id. You can see the below link for the dynamic generated HTML.

[Dymanic Generated HTML](https://jsfiddle.net/okhqhnxb/2/)

So for saving this, I need some suggestion on how to save it in javascript. I tried the other fields of the HTML..

```js
function SaveNPEDetails() {

    var DashboardFields = {};

    if ($('#ddlFiberised').val() == '--Select--' || $('#ddlFiberised').val() == null) {
        alert('Please select FIBERISED');
        return false;
    }
    else {
        DashboardFields.NPEFiberised = $('#ddlFiberised').val();
    }

    if ($('#txtNoFDPSite').val() == '' || $('#txtNoFDPSite').val() == null) {
        alert('Please add NO. OF FDP AT SITE');
        return false;
    }
    else {
        DashboardFields.NoOfFDPatSite = $('#txtNoFDPSite').val();
    }

    if ($('#txtNoOfRoutesTerAtFDP').val() == '' || $('#txtNoOfRoutesTerAtFDP').val() == null) {
        alert('Please add NO. OF ROUTES TERMINATED AT FDP');
        return false;
    }
    else {
        DashboardFields.NoOfRoutesTermAtFDP = $('#txtNoOfRoutesTerAtFDP').val();
    }
// Need to write saving logic for dynamic generated html here. 
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "DashboardData.aspx/UpdateNPEData",
        data: JSON.stringify({ DashboardFields: DashboardFields }),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            alert(response.d);
        },
        error: function (response) {
            alert('Something went wrong..!!');
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: please care to comment on downvote

Comment: What do you mean by saving? You'll probably need a database for that.

Comment: @Paul: can u explain how ?

Comment: Why do you use `id` for dynamic generated elements?

Comment: @TimGerhard: this is client side code, I will handle the database part ?

Comment: @Sabbin: then what should I use, I will have to rebind again on page load

Comment: are you trying to read the data?

Comment: @BNN, your HTML and JS code does not in sync, both has different ids.

Comment: So all you worry about is how to send your dynamic via ajax post to a database / controller? So your question should be "send dynamic html via ajax"

Comment: @AlpeshJikadra: Please check now..all html are in link

Comment: @TimGerhard: yes, ok got it.

Comment: I understand that you want to have dynamic fields and a submit somewhere on the line, why don't you use `class` for distinct `input` types, one for `select` and one for `text` and at the `submit` function you just verify all of the `inputs` via one single `function` and construct your `DashboardFields` object then

Comment: @RanjitSingh: yes, I want to read the data and submit it

Comment: Which data you want to send first row or all rows ?

Comment: @AlpeshJikadra: As much data will be filled, I want all that data.

Comment: I'm working on a fiddle for you

Comment: @BNN - add class in each control and iterate over it and read the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per our discussion you can try something like

```
function SaveNPEDetails() { 
        var data = []; 
        var DashboardFields = {}; 

        if ($('#ddlFiberised').val() == '--Select--' || $('#ddlFiberised').val() == null) { 
        alert('Please select FIBERISED'); 
        return false; 
        } 
        else { 
        DashboardFields.NPEFiberised = $('#ddlFiberised').val(); 
        } 

        if ($('#txtNoFDPSite').val() == '' || $('#txtNoFDPSite').val() == null) { 
        alert('Please add NO. OF FDP AT SITE'); 
        return false; 
        } 
        else { 
        DashboardFields.NoOfFDPatSite = $('#txtNoFDPSite').val(); 
        } 

        if ($('#txtNoOfRoutesTerAtFDP').val() == '' || $('#txtNoOfRoutesTerAtFDP').val() == null) { 
        alert('Please add NO. OF ROUTES TERMINATED AT FDP'); 
        return false; 
        } 
        else { 
        DashboardFields.NoOfRoutesTermAtFDP = $('#txtNoOfRoutesTerAtFDP').val(); 
        } 



        var chs = $("#dvNPEAddData").children(".addNPEData") 

        for (var i = 0; i < chs.length; i++) { 
            var d = {}; 
            var ch = chs[i]; 
            var val = $(ch).find("input[name='TerRouteName']").val(); 
            d[$(ch).find("input[name='TerRouteName']").attr("name")] = val; 

            val = $(ch).find("select[name='CableType']").val(); 
            d[$(ch).find("select[name='CableType']").attr("name")] = val; 

            val = $(ch).find("select[name='CableSize']").val(); 
            d[$(ch).find("select[name='CableSize']").attr("name")] = val; 


            val = $(ch).find("input[name='NoLiveFibre']").val(); 
            d[$(ch).find("input[name='NoLiveFibre']").attr("name")] = val; 

            data.push(d); 
        } 

        var d = JSON.stringify(data);

        $.ajax({ 

             type: "POST", 
            url: "DashboardData.aspx/UpdateNPEData", 
            data: JSON.stringify({ DashboardFields: DashboardFields , myJsonXML : d}), 
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", 
            dataType: "json", 
            success: function (response) { 
            alert(response.d); 
            }, 
            error: function (response) { 
            alert('Something went wrong..!!'); 
            } 
        }); 

}
```

Comment: Not getting any values..length is coming `0`

Comment: Assign name to each field

Comment: hi, I want to add validation on the dynamic generated fields.. how should I do it ?

Comment: You can add new question for that

Comment: @BNN you can add that validation in for loop

Comment: i know, will ask a question later but its urgent now..can u come on chat so that we can discuss it and finish it. if possbile please come here  https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167715/discussion-between-alpesh-jikadra-and-bnn

Answer (score 1):

Using your example in the fiddle I've done the following

```
$('#submit').click(function() {
   var DashboardFields = {},
   status = true;

   $.each($('input[type="text"]'), function(i, v) {
       var id = $(v).attr('id');
       if ($(v).val() == '') {
          alert(id + ' field is empty');
          status = false;
       } else {
          DashboardFields[id] = $(v).val();
       }
   });

   $.each($('select'), function(i, v) {
       var id = $(v).attr('id');
       if ($(v).val() == '--Select--' || $(v).val() == null) {
            alert(id + ' select is empty');
            status = false;
       } else {
            DashboardFields[id] = $(v).val();
       }
   });
   if(!status){
      alert('you have empty fields');
   } else {
      console.log(DashboardFields); //Here should be your Ajax Call
   }  
});
```

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/okhqhnxb/19/)

I've used your example with ID's and created a filter in order to take dynamically the fields not by ID's, I used the ID's to map the `DashboardFields` object but I strongly encourage to use `name` or other `data-` param and change the jQuery code after (the line with `var id=$(v).attr('id')`)

Hope this helps you

Comment: let me try and check

Comment: hi, how can we do on the basis of name, I have added name to each control. see this https://jsfiddle.net/uwvajhj1/

Comment: I've done a little bit more abstract on the jQuery code check it here -> https://jsfiddle.net/okhqhnxb/25/

Comment: I'll check your fiddle now

Comment: sure and let me know.

Comment: check the `console` - your browser console - if you have completed all the fields you should see an object with all the data when you press submit

Comment: i have other input htmls here which is been validated..continous alert i  m getting

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167720/discussion-between-sabbin-and-bnn).

Comment: upvoted ur answer, Alpesh's answer was working perfectly fine :) thanks for giving it a try